# Ubuntu 18.04 clevis decrypt of secondary disk

Tags: mount, 18.04, encryption, luks

Running Ubuntu 18.04 with an unencrypted root volume. For what I need this to do, that's fine. But I need to mount and decrypt secondary disks. Following Red Hat's directions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_network-bound_disk_encryption) since every google search for Ubuntu and NBDE/Clevis&Tang takes me there.

*This procedure works flawlessly on RHEL 7.x and CentOS 7.x.

I've gotten as far as partitioning (not using LVM here), encrypting, binding it to a tang server.

First I install the packages:

```
apt-get install clevis clevis-systemd clevis-dracut clevis-luks
```

Then I set up the disk

```
echo '<TEMPPASS>'| cryptsetup --verbose luksFormat /dev/xvdc1

clevis bind luks -f -k- -d /dev/xvdc1 tang '{"url":"http://<IP>:<PORT>","thp":"<KEY>"}' <<< "<TEMPPASS>"

echo "<TEMPPASS>" | cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/xvdc1

clevis luks unlock -d /dev/xvdc1 -n testluksvol
```

And Bob's your Auntie. Then I format it and verify it can mount.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/testluksvol

mount /dev/mapper/testluksvol /testluksvol
```

So far so good. I add the entries to /etc/fstab using _netdev as the directions said:

```
/dev/mapper/testluksvol /testluksvol    ext4    defaults,_netdev 0 2
```

Add the entry to /etc/crypttab, also with _netdev, though I didn't think Ubuntu crypttab supported that since it isn't in the crypttab manpage, but whatevs. We're making Chef Boy'R'D here, not world class bolognese:

```
testluksvol     UUID=<DEVICE UUID>       none    _netdev
```

And finally, enable clevis-luks-askpass.path

```
systemctl enable clevis-luks-askpass.path
```

Then we reboot... and it doesn't work. So we go look in /var/log/syslog and see this:

```
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72ebf50e\x2dc3de\x2d468a\x2d89c3\x2defc869757a51.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72ebf50e\x2dc3de\x2d468a\x2d89c3\x2defc86975
7a51.device/start timed out.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72ebf50e\x2dc3de\x2d468a\x2d89c3\x2defc869757a51.device.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for testluksvol.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dev-mapper-testluksvol.device.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /testluksvol.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: remote-fs.target: Job remote-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: testluksvol.mount: Job testluksvol.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/testluksvol.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-testluksvol.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-testluksvol.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: dev-mapper-testluksvol.device: Job dev-mapper-testluksvol.device/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: cryptsetup.target: Job cryptsetup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@testluksvol.service: Job systemd-cryptsetup@testluksvol.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 22 23:06:22 ubuntu03 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72ebf50e\x2dc3de\x2d468a\x2d89c3\x2defc869757a51.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72ebf50e\x2dc3de\x2d468a\x2d89c3\x2defc86975
7a51.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

This is a bit beyond frustrating. I got 18.04 specifically because it was supposed to have support for clevis & tang. I wanted to integrate it into an existing env that is running tang servers.

Can anyone, for the love of Linus Torvalds, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found that my disk UUID was incorrect. Once I updated that to the correct one, this whole procedure worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To create, encrypt or decrypt LUKS encrypted disk, you can simply use cryptsetup.

For example, I'll allocate a test.img to use as an example for an empty disk partition. I'll create a LUKS encrypted disk volume, format it, and then mount it.

```
fallocate -l 1G test.img

sudo cryptsetup create test test.img
Enter passphrase for test.img: 
sudo mkfs -t ext2 /dev/mapper/test 

mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Creating filesystem with 262144 4k blocks and 65536 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 5f58a7a0-6139-4ae3-b423-be86dbc90874
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

sudo mount /dev/mapper/test /mnt

df /mnt
Filesystem       1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/test   1032088  1284    978376   1% /mnt
```

You can then use the decrypted volume mounted on /mnt/. To umount and remove the decrypted volume.

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo cryptsetup remove test
```

Later when you need to use the mount the encrypted volume, just do the following.

```
sudo cryptsetup create test test.img
Enter passphrase for test.img: 

sudo mount /dev/mapper/test /mnt

df /mnt

Filesystem       1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/test   1032088  1284    978376   1% /mnt
```

If you want it to mount automatically with password prompt, add the following.

```
mv test.img /
sudo vi /etc/crypttab
```

and add the following line

```
/mnt /test.img none luks
```

On bootup, you'll be promted to the password for mounting the volume. If you don't want to have to enter the password, you may use a key-file.

PS: Oh nevermind, just realized you needed to get the pass key from network, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the question... Thanks for responding though :-)